# How to change the input value in android Edit Tex?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I entered `586785865858586` in android edit text but the value is converted in to `5.8678585E17` .But i need the same input that i give .Please any one help me in this

my xml code

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etOpenText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </EditText>
```

Java code

```
String s=edittext.getText().tostring();
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `EditText`. You have entered a value that is too much to convert to either `int` or `float`.

Comment: put your Edit text code here...

Comment: can you please provide the xml code where you have added the edittext and also the java code where you get the value out of it?

Comment: xml code <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etOpenText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:visibility="gone" >
            </EditText>

Comment: change String s=edittext.getText().tostring();

Comment: double value = Double.parseDouble(edittext.getText()); might work?

Answer (score 1):

You are telling the edit text that it is supposed to expect a number. Just make it one that is expecting a string.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/myNumber"
android:digits="0123456780."
android:inputType="text"
/>
```

android:digits="0123456780." Limits input to those digits. You might have to change the input type to numberDecimal

If you want to get the double behind the scenes do:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(textview.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to modify your xml to

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/etOpenText" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
 android:layout_height="120dp" 
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
 android:gravity="top" 
 android:inputType="number" 
 android:visibility="gone" />
```

or

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/etOpenText" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
 android:layout_height="120dp" 
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
 android:gravity="top" 
 android:digits="0123456780"
 android:inputType="text"
 android:visibility="gone" />
```

To get the value back you and use it as a value you can do

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(edittext.getText());
```